# Unity 3D, transform.position not working on instatiate object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have create a simple script that instantiates a Cube. I need to know its location (x and z). However, when the script instantiates the cube, its x and z positions are 0. What am I doing wrong?

Instantiate Script Example:

```
public GameObject cube;
float xPos, zPos;
int randomPos;

void Start()
{
    randomPos = Random.Range(10,20);
    Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(1,0,randomPos),Quaternion.identity);

    xPos = cube.transform.position.x;
    zPos = cube.transform.position.z;
}
```

This is an example, i need to know the "cube.transform.position.x and z" But the output is always zero  Thanks guys

[image]

[image]

Comment: well .. `cube` is the prefab that is not in the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the position not of your cube, but from the new one created by `Instantiate`.
`Instantiate` clones the object original and returns the clone.

```
void Start(){

randomPos = Random.Range(10,20);
var newCube = Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(1,0,randomPos),Quaternion.identity);

xPos = newCube.transform.position.x;
zPos = newCube.transform.position.z;

}
```